# create multiple buttons from table in lua ( Corona sdk )

Tags: button, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I have a table which looks like this:

```
table = 
{
{
    id = 1,
    name = 'john',
    png = 'john.png',
    descr = "..."
},
{
    id = 2,
    name = 'sam',
    png = "sam.png",
    descr = "..."
}
...
}
```

What function could I use to display each picture like this and make them buttons [image]

so that when I click on their image I can open their info.

This is where I am stuck:

```
local buttons =  display.newGroup()
local xpos = -20
local ypos = 0
local e = -1


function addpicture ()
    for i=1, #table do
        xpos = (xpos + 100) % 300
        e = e + 1
        ypos = math.modf((e)*1/3) * 100 + 100
        local c = display.newImage( table[i].name, system.TemporaryDirectory, xpos, ypos)
        c:scale( 0.4, 0.4 )
        c.name = table[i].tvname
        buttons:insert(c)
    end
end

function buttons:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print(self, event.id)   
    end
end
buttons:addEventListener('touch', buttons)
addpicture()
```

How can I recognize which image is touched in order to go back to the persons info?

Comment: You can use display.newImageRect() with appropriate png, and set listeners on them to open info, or you can use widget.newButton(). What difficulty do you have with your current code?

Comment: My problem is that I can not create each button separately because I do not know how many there will be, each user will need to have a different set of buttons.

Comment: Then you loop through the table and create appropriate number of buttons, based on what's in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the listener inside of the loop like this:

```
function addpicture ()
    for i=1, #table do
       xpos = (xpos + 100) % 300
       e = e + 1
       ypos = math.modf((e)*1/3) * 100 + 100
       local c = display.newImage( table[i].name, system.TemporaryDirectory, xpos, ypos)
       c:scale( 0.4, 0.4 )
       c.name = table[i].tvname
       buttons:insert(c)
       function c:touch( event )
         if event.phase == "began" then
            print(self, event.id)   
         end
       end
       c:addEventListener('touch', c)
    end
end
addpicture()
```

Comment: This makes sense because previously, you were setting listener on the whole display group, not on an individual button, as you're doing it now.